# Logging methodology in a Meteor application

Tags: node.js, logging, meteor, winston

I'm building my first meteor app (my background is writing C++ systems), and I'm struggling for a while with the logging methodology of the app.

After trying the winston log package, I've understood that there is a problem with issuing log calls from code which is shared between the client and the server (as the log might write to a file on the server's file system). For instance, methods.js code, which is intended to run from the server but is simulated at the client for optimistic UI.

I would love to get some ideas of how to log code which is shared between the client and server, or the general methodology in this case. I wouldn't want to wrap each call with "Meteor.isServer" condition, of course...

Thanks and best regards

Comment: What do you want to do with the simulated logging messages generated on the client? What are you experiencing that differs from the desired outcome? What is you Winston setup? There are multiple Meteor packages with different behavior and bindings. If you simply want to ask folks regarding their logging methodology, I believe the Meteor forums are more useful.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the question was general. I've already asked the forum, but haven't got any responses yet unfortunately. Anyway, the way I solved it, currently, is by defining a global logger variable which on the client is calling a Method and of the server ignores in case of a simulation. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works.

Comment: Well, it's similar to the approach taken by [this Meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/clinical/winston-browser-logging). I don't log the client activity the same way I do server activity, as those are different concerns and contexts, and I have different versions for methods for the client and the server.